# "Incompatible pointer type.." when trying to sort using `sortedArrayUsingFunction`

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am trying to sort an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`s basing on a price field.

```
NSString* priceComparator(NSMutableDictionary *obj1, NSMutableDictionary *obj2, void *context){

    return @"just for test for the moment";

}

//In other function
arrayProduct = (NSMutableArray*)[arrayProduct sortedArrayUsingFunction:priceComparator context:nil];//arrayProduct is NSMutableArray containing NSDictionarys
```

On the statement above, I am getting the following warning which I want to fix:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSString*(NSMutableDictionary *__strong,NSMutableDictionary *__strong,void*)' to parameter of type 'NSInteger (*)(__strong id, __strong id, void*)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error states, your `priceComparator` function [needs to be declared as returning `NSInteger`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003620), not `NSString *`:

```
NSInteger priceComparator(NSMutableDictionary *obj1, NSMutableDictionary *obj2, void *context){
    if (/* obj1 should sort before obj2 */)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (/* obj1 should sort after obj2 */)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Better yet, you could use [`NSSortDescriptors`](http://nshipster.com/nssortdescriptor/) if the price you need to sort by is a simple numeric value that's always at a given key in these dictionaries. I think this is the syntax:

```
id descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedProducts = [arrayProduct sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

Also note that all of the `sortedArray...` methods return a new, plain `NSArray` object, not a `NSMutableArray`. Thus the `sortedProducts` declaration in the sample code above. If you really do need your sorted array to still be mutable, you could use the [`sortUsingFunction:context:` or `sortUsingDescriptors:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method of NSMutableArray to sort the array in-place. Note that these methods return `void`, so you wouldn't assign the result to any variable, it would modify your `arrayProduct` object in-place.